# Cannot run selenium java program after adding 3.0 jar file

Tags: java, selenium

I updated my project to use Marionette/gecko and when I try to run it I get this message:

```
1477424937782   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:11146
Oct 25, 2016 3:48:58 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
1477424938364   mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path C:\Users\Janet\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.iMfi1TUVjDFi
1477424938367   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
1477424938372   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:50333
1477424939344   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 50333
Oct 25, 2016 3:49:01 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
JavaScript warning: https://normandy.cdn.mozilla.net/static/bundles/selfrepair-910943d53dbd84b4c75a.a958f9d28733.js, line 7: mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create
Element users was not found
```

Comment: Could you share your problematic code as well??

Comment: `//Set up webdriver
   System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Janet\\Downloads\\Marionette\\geckodriver.exe");
   driver = new FirefoxDriver();
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   driver.manage().window().maximize();
   
   //Set up website and login
   setup(envUrl + "//login", userName, pwd);
   
   driver.get(envUrl + "/admin/media");`

Comment: This is what the setup method looks like`public void setup(String web, String user, String password) {
  try {
   //Go to website
   driver.get(web);
   
   //Clear and fill in email
  // clearb("email");
   tbox("email", user);
   
   //Clear and fill in password
  // clearb("password");
   tbox("password", password);
     
   //Click on login
   cssbutton("button.button");
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   System.err.println("Error occurred while setting up website");
   System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
   driver.quit();
  }
 }`

Comment: My problem is that when the login button is selected it never goes to the new page it just blanks out the email and password fields.

Comment: Should also mention that I am using Firefox version 49.0.2 and so now what I get is a little more information:  `###!!! [Child][MessageChannel] Error: (msgtype=0x400003,name=PCompositable::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot send/recv

[Child 11288] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2052`

Answer (score 0):

use below code. You need to set the system property so that your geckodriver can be located

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\geckodriver.exe");


        driver = new MarionetteDriver();
```

Comment: That did not work either.   And I got a message saying that MarionetteDriver is deprecated anyway.   Thanks though it was worth a shot.

Comment: I had already set the system property:  `System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Janet\\Downloads\\Marionette\\geckodriver.exe"); driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

Comment: There may be some conflict with the FF version

Comment: try with below system property also                                                                                      System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","G:\\Selenium\\Firefox driver\\geckodriver.exe")